# React native app to receive share links from apps like youtube

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to React native. I am developing an app to receive shared url like in youtube share which shares the url.[image: like this] I have added the code to register receive activity in xml like this

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
 </intent-filter>
```

But in my App.js code how could i receive the data and do further processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Deep Linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html#docsNav) from `react-navigation`. Check this [Article](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e) for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [react-native-share-extension](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension)

Comment: If you want to open your app instead of displaying a popup you will have to do your own module :(

Answer (score 4):

So get the initial launched url you can actually use the inbuild react-native functionality of `Linking` where in you main/root file you can just listen you initial launch params as

```
   componentDidMount = () => {
       Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
       // if your app was launched from the share you will get the text
       // else url will be null
       if (url) {
         console.log('shared string/text is ', url);
       }
     }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
   }
```

[React native Linking docs link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#handling-deep-links)

Comment: Awesome. I thought about going with Firebase Dynamic Links. but this is also same as expected

Answer (score 1):

I got the easy way to get the shared text value from other apps as mentioned in the [article](https://www.bennettnotes.com/react-native-android-receive-data-from-share-intent/)

This lets us to get the shared text in `render props` for the app initially.